# How to move multiple files when moving only one file

Tags: windows, file, save, html, move

If you've ever saved a a full webpage you'll notice that it creates the .htm file and a folder that contains all the icons and scripts for the page.

If you move the .htm file to a new location, the folder that came with it moves to the same location, and the behavior is the same if you move the folder, the .htm file will move with it.

How can I do that with any old file/folder combination? Can this be manipulated?

EDIT: Programmatically (through CMD)

Is there a command that binds files to other files etc.?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: made an edit =D. sorry. I would think that something has to be done to the file, i.e. permissions or something, and that can be done through the command line. Which when dealing with files remotely, this would be useful.

Comment: @Mechaflash Well the command line is not a programming tool its just another interface to the os. I woudl think you are better off asking this on superuseers or serverfault if its server management related.

Comment: @Iznogood you can however insert the command into a windows batch file. So I suppose it would work in either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the shell called [Connected Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#connected).  It is specifically implemented for web pages; it is not generic or extensible as far as I know.

It doesn't even seem that useful to me as it only works when using the shell mechanisms (SHFileOperation and friends); if plain old CopyFile/MoveFile are used then all the files need to be handled individually.